# Linux system freezes when adb start-server is called

Tags: linux, adb, fedora

The command `adb start-server` is freezing my system entirely, requiring a hard reset to recover.

This is a fresh install of **Fedora 21 (x86_64)**. When the system freezes, it is immediate.  The desktop stops responding, the computer no longer accepts ping requests, and nothing is logged in the system messages.

This happens whether I run `adb` as root or a regular user. When I run the command, it says: `daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037` 
and the freeze is immediate. It never does return that the daemon was started.

I installed strace and ran:

```
# strace adb start-server
```

and the final few lines of output were:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5037), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
close(3)                                = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf75ef000
write(1, "* daemon not running. starting i"..., 53* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
) = 53
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
readlink("/proc/1880/exe", "/home/jon/Android/Sdk/platform-t"..., 4095) = 40
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xf727c768) = 1881
close(4)                                = 0
read(3,
```

This freeze happens regardless of whether I have a USB device plugged in or not. Other than this issue, the computer seems to work fine.

Is there some hardware on the computer that `adb` is initializing, that might be causing this freeze? I'd be grateful for pointers on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I reinstalled Fedora into a 32 bit version and cannot reproduce the error. So this problem is restricted to the 64 bit environment.

Comment: Does *Magic Sysrq* key combination still work? Any signs of kernel oops / panic (i.e. flashing caps lock / num lock)? If you do it in Linux console (i.e. not in xterm, so you can see kernel console output), does it show any kernel crash messages / traces?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a solution, because the freeze is realy hard to debug, but a workaround. As I suspected the problem is related to the kernel version.

I downgraded the kernel installed and `adb` works fine without any freeze.
Go on a repository and download manually these package:

```
 - kernel-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.rpm
 - kernel-debug-devel-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.rpm  
 - kernel-modules-extra-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.rpm
 - kernel-core-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.rpm  
 - kernel-modules-3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

Install it with the command `rpm -ivh --force kernel-*` reboot the
computer and select the new kernel when `grub` show.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Acer Aspire E17, i didn't found the exact component, but it works perfect when using UEFI bios, so the problem is that they don't put too much effor making and testing the Legacy bios.

You can install Fedora in UEFI mode with some effort. You will not fix a bios fail problem.

[Install Fedora UEFI](http://www.zdnet.com/pictures/how-i-installed-fedora-18-with-uefi-secure-boot/)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:*

I still had the issue on my Lenovo E40 laptop with Arch Linux x86_64. When adb was started, it would freeze the machine immediately.

Changing from BIOS to UEFI boot did not solve the problem.

**Downgrading to kernel version 3.16 LTS solved it.
Now `adb` works normally. Now it works both under BIOS and UEFI, so it's not related to these.**

I have also tried the 4.4 LTS kernel, later 4.x kernels, two different 5.0.13 kernels, and adb freezes on all of them.

When I had previously tried the solution with rebooting multiple times until it worked, it was under an early 4.x kernel. I had to reboot around 32-64 times until it worked. With later 4.x and 5.x kernels, this solution stopped working. I have tried rebooting the machine up to about 128 times on these later kernels, without success.

Now `adb` works nomally under the 3.16 LTS kernel, I haven't tried other 3.x kernels.

(This kernel also seems to handle my laptop's ACPI functions properly, now the soft shutdown and soft reset works normally. These didn't work under 4.x and 5.x.)

*Original answer:*

I also had this exact issue (but on Arch Linux x86_64). I wasn't able to resolve it.

I noticed that adb does sometimes work without freezing, depending on reboot. **After adb works once, it will always work until the next reboot.**

So it's possible to use it normally if you reboot a few times until it works.

.

Possibly related discussion: [What's changed with USB drivers in 4.0 and later Linux kernels?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239637/whats-changed-with-usb-drivers-in-4-0-and-later-linux-kernels)